# Widget select option not saving

Tags: widgets, select

I do this widget but the selected options dont saving when updated. This is the code:

```
/* CUSTOM POSTS LIST */
class Posts_list extends WP_Widget {

    function Posts_list() {
        /* Widget settings. */
        $widget_ops = array( 'classname' => 'posts_list', 'description' => __('Display differents posts list.', 'fabulous') );
        /* Widget control settings. */
        $control_ops = array( 'width' => 200, 'height' => 350, 'id_base' => 'posts_list' );
        /* Create the widget. */
        $this->WP_Widget( 'posts_list', __('Fabulous posts list', 'fabulous'), $widget_ops, $control_ops );
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        extract( $args );
        /* User-selected settings. */
        $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $id = $instance['id'];
        $type = $instance['type'];
        $num = $instance['num'];
        $img = $instance['img'];
        $meta = $instance['meta'];

        /* Before widget (defined by themes). */
        echo $before_widget;

        /* Title of widget (before and after defined by themes). */
        if ( $title )
            echo $before_title . $title . $after_title; ?>

        <div id="<?php echo $id ?>">
        <?php if ( $type == 'Recent posts' ) {
            echo fab_recent_posts($num, $img, $meta);
        } elseif ($type == 'Popular posts') {
            echo fab_popular_posts($num, $img, $meta);
        } elseif ($type == 'Top rating posts') {
            echo fab_top_rating($num, $img, $meta);
        } ?>
        </div>
        <?php 

        /* After widget (defined by themes). */
        echo $after_widget;
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        /* Strip tags (if needed) and update the widget settings. */
        $instance['title'] = strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] );
        $instance['id'] = $new_instance['id'];
        $instance['type'] = $new_instance['type'];
        $instance['num'] = $new_instance['num'];
        $instance['img'] =  isset( $new_instance['img'] );
        $instance['meta'] =  isset( $new_instance['meta'] );
        return $instance;
    }

    function form( $instance ) {
        /* Set up some default widget settings. */
        $defaults = array( 'title' => '', 'id' =>'posts-list-widget', 'type' => 'recents-posts', 'num' => '5', 'img' => 1, 'meta' => 1);    
        $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults ); 
        $type = isset( $new_instance['type'] );
        ?>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>">
<?php _e('Title:', 'fabulous') ?>
</label>
<input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['title']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'id' ); ?>">
<?php _e('Name:', 'fabulous') ?>
</label>
<input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'id' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'id' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['id']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
</p>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('type'); ?>">
<?php _e('Choose posts list type:', 'fabulous'); ?>
</label>
<select name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('type'); ?>" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('type'); ?>" class="widefat">
<?php
$types = array ('Recent posts', 'Top rating posts', 'Popular posts');
foreach ($types as $option) {
echo '<option value="' . $option . '" id="' . $option . '"', $type == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
}?>
</select>
</p>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'num' ); ?>">
<?php _e('Number of posts:', 'fabulous') ?>
</label>
<input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'num' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'num' ); ?>" value="<?php echo $instance['num']; ?>" style="width:100%;" />
</p>
<p>
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked(isset( $instance['img']) ? $instance['img'] : 0  ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'showrecents' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'img' ); ?>" />
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'img' ); ?>">
<?php _e('Display image', 'fabulous') ?>
</label>
</p>
<p>
  <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" <?php checked(isset( $instance['meta']) ? $instance['meta'] : 0  ); ?> id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'meta' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'meta' ); ?>" />
  <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'meta' ); ?>">
<?php _e('Display meta', 'fabulous') ?>
</label>
</p>
<?php
    }

}
```

Nobody can help me please? Thanks!

Comment: "do not saving" is a very brief error description.

Answer (score 1):

This line `$type = isset( $instance['type'] );` will set `$type` to either `true` or `false` which never matches the string you check for later:

```
foreach ($types as $option) {
   echo '<option value="' . $option . '" id="' . $option . '"', $type == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
}
```

You need to remove that `$type = isset( $instance['type'] );` line and use `$instance['type']` in the `option`.

You should also consider using [`selected()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected).